# PHP Compare 2 big multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a task to compare 100 000 records multidimensional array with itself.
The structure of array is :

```
array(
    ['webpage_url'] => array(
    2174418388,
    1751917480,
    2104295597
    ... up to 2000 crc32 hashes
     )
 )
```

The simple code i am using is :

```
 $pages = array_keys($this->_pageShingls);
    foreach ($pages as $firstPage) {
        $firstShingles = $this->_pageShingls[$firstPage];
        foreach ($pages as $secondPage) {
            if ($secondPage !== $firstPage) {
                foreach ($this->_pageShingls[$secondPage] as $hash => $sh) {
                    if (isset($firstShingles[$hash])) {
                        if (!isset($shinglIntersection[$firstPage][$secondPage])) {
                            $shingleIntersection[$firstPage][$secondPage] = 0;
                        } else {
                            ++$shingleIntersection[$firstPage][$secondPage];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

One upmost loop iteration takes about 2 seconds on my machine. And i have to do 100 000 of those! Is there a way to do this work faster?

Comment: What is the desired result? Could you add example of input data and output data?

Comment: How do the names used in your code relate to the array you provide? What do you actually want as output?